# What is the best package for dict filter

Tags: python, package

What is the best package to easy filter ? like django-filter but i outside the django object.

for example

```
>>dict = {
{'name':'apple','amount':10},
{'name':'apple','amount':5},
{'name':'banana','amount':10},
{'name':'green-apple','amount':20},
}

>>filter(dict,name='apple')
{'name':'apple','amount':10},{'name':'apple','amount':10}

 >>filter(dict,name='apple',amount=10)
{'name':'apple','amount':10}

 >>filter(dict,amount_gt=5)
{'name':'apple','amount':10},{'name':'banana','amount':10}

 >>filter(dict,amount_gte=5)
{'name':'apple','amount':10},{'name':'apple','amount':5},{'name':'banana','amount':10}

 >>filter(dict,amount_lt=10)
{'name':'apple','amount':5}

 >>filter(dict,name_regex=".*apple")
{'name':'apple','amount':5},{'name':'apple','amount':10},{'name':'green-apple','amount':20}
```

Comment: You named your variable `dict` (bad idea to shadow the built-in `dict`), and it's not actually a `dict` anyway; that's not even legal code, because you're trying to make a `set` of `dict`s, and `dict`s aren't hashable.

Comment: Also, in order to be valid, the dict key must be an immutable type, such as a string or number

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function like this:

```
def filter_dicts(dict_list, **kwargs):
    for item in dict_list:
        if all(item[k] == v for k, v in kwargs.items()):
            yield item
```

usage:

```
dict_list = [
    {"name": "apple", "amount": 10},
    {"name": "apple", "amount": 15},
    {"name": "orange", "amount": 5}
]

for d in filter_dicts(dict_list, name="apple", amount=10):
    print(d)
```

Or, alternatively you can do this:

```
filtered_dicts = [item for item in dict_list if item["amount"] > 10 and item["name"] == "apple"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user `items` to convert dict to a list
and use filter on that list, namely

```
filter(lambda x : x[0] == 'amount', dict.items())
```

an you can convert it back too